# How to get IPV6 address from hostname

Tags: java

Can anyone please suggest me how to get IPV6 address fro hostname which contains both IPV4 and IPV6 addresses.

I tried to get it using `java.net.InetAddress.getHostAddress`, but it is only giving me the  ipv4.

Answer (score 2):

Use `InetAddress.getAllByName("your.host.name")`. From the javadoc:

```
Given the name of a host, returns an array of its IP addresses, based on the configured name service on the system.
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `java.net.Inet6Address.getHostAddress()`

Comment: This method does not exist on `Inet6Address`, it is only declared on `InetAddress`. So it does not have any Ipv6 specific handling.

Answer (score 1):

```
   InetAddress ip;
    String hostname;
    try {
        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();    // getlocalhost               
        hostname = ip.getHostName();   //hostname you got locally 
        InetAddress[] inet = InetAddress.getAllByName(hostname); //it will return ipv4 and ipv6
   
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use

```
java.net.inet6address.getHostAddress
```

Comment: There is no java.net.Inet6Address.getHostAddress!

Comment: Sure there is.  Here's the docs:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/Inet6Address.html#getHostAddress()

Comment: There is not. The method that exists is not `static`, so it is useless for discovery of addresses.